# Group by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table of the following structure:

```
ID | COMPANY_ID | VERSION | TEXT
---------------------------------
 1 |     1      |    1    | hello
 2 |     1      |    2    | world
 3 |     2      |    1    |  foo
```

is there a way to get the most recent version of records only, i.e. I would want to have as a result set the IDs 2 and 3?

Comment: Why only 2 and 3? You only want the 2 latest records?

Comment: @matino 2 & 3 have the `MAX(VERSION)` by `COMPANY_ID`

Comment: @matino: If I understood right: retrieve ID for each company_id with the highest version

Comment: @Michael: And that's basically the answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways, but I tend to use this kind of query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY VERSION DESC) AS my_table
GROUP BY COMPANY_ID
```

Produces this result set:

```
ID | COMPANY_ID | VERSION | TEXT
---------------------------------
 2 |     1      |    2    | world
 3 |     2      |    1    |  foo
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT company_id, MAX(version) maxVersion
    FROM table
    GROUP BY company_id ) as val
JOIN table t ON (val.company_id = t.company_id AND t.version = val.maxversion)
```

Comment: You need to add the t alias after the 'JOIN table'

Answer (score 0):

If your IDs are ordered (newer version iff higher id):

```
SELECT t.*, a.maxversion
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(id) maxid, MAX(version) maxversion
  FROM table
  GROUP BY company_id
) a
INNER JOIN table t
ON a.maxid = t.id
```

However, if your IDs are not properly ordered, you need to use the following query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT company_id, MAX(version) maxversion
  FROM table
  GROUP BY company_id
) v
INNER JOIN table t
ON v.company_id = t.company_id
AND v.maxversion = t.version
```

(assuming there's an `UNIQUE` constraint/index on `(company_id, version)`)